# "This does not seem to be a "Debug" build." when trying to debug in QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I created a simple `main.cpp` file and a makefile for it.

Started Qt Creator and then imported the project.

The program compiles just fine but I can't debug it. It always show me this error:

```
This does not seem to be a "Debug" build. 
Setting breakpoints by file name and line number may fail.
Section .debug_info: Not found. 
Section .debug_abbrev: Not found.
Section .debug_line: Not found. 
Section .debug_str: Not found.  
Section .debug_loc: Not found. 
Section .debug_range: Not found.  
Section .gdb_index: Not found. 
Section .note.gnu.build-id: Found.  
Section .gnu.hash: Found. 
Section .gnu_debuglink: Not found.
```

In makefile I have the following code for debug:

```
debug: CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -g  
debug: $(EXECUTABLE)
```

I already tried in `Build Steps` to pass as argument "debug" (make debug all) so it forces to compile with the `-DDEBUG` and `-g` flags and it shows me the same error.

Do you guys have any solution for this?

Comment: Maybe you need to change the CXXFLAGS as well.

Comment: I didn't defined any CXXFLAGS, only CFLAGS (CFLAGS=-c -Wall)

Comment: Avoid specify `CONFIG += -DDEBUG -g`, rather pass it on `qmake` parameter, something like: `qmake projectname.pro linux-g++ CONFIG += debug`.

Comment: Also note, `Makefile` should be auto-generated don't try to run the `Makefile` which was generated on some other environment.

Comment: @rakib_ I'm not using qmake because I can't compile the program it always says it can't start the process make or something like that. 

So i created the makefile and then inserted the rules I wanted/needed. After that I imported the project on Qt. This way I can compile. But I want to debug my app and I can't even with the debug rule on makefile.

Comment: You should be using `qmake` for building `Qt` project. You can try opening a new project and manually adding the source files, in case you already don't have a `.pro` file. Qt creator internally runs `qmake` to produce Makefile. This is the standard way to go in `Qt`.

Comment: @rakib_ created a new project and copy the code I had written to a new files. It compiled and now I can debug. I just don't understand why before didn't worked, always said the process couldn't start. Now everything worked fine... Thanks for your help :)